# Permission denied trying to initiate script execution in Android OS

Tags: java, android

Having trouble kicking off a bash shell script in Android OS.  Using Android Studio and a Google Pixel emulator.  Getting "permission denied" on the script execution.  The permission on the script is "755".  Let me know if I have something wrong here.  Note- when I do:
`%adb shell`
`%run-as com.example.myapplication`.
`%./getinfo.sh`.
it runs OK.

It just won't run when the script is being kicked off in the app's Java code in the Android emulator.  Let me know if I have something wrong here.
Thanks!

The relevant java code--

```
String command="/data/data/com.example.myapplication/getinfo.sh"; 
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command); 
Process p = builder.start();
p.waitFor();.
```

The errors listed by logcat are--

```
05-27 13:37:46.588  9348  9348 I System.out: -   command=/data/data/com.example.myapplication/getinfo.sh^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/data/com.example.myapplication/getinfo.sh": error=13, Permission denied^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:227)^M.    
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)^M    
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:801)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27336)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)^M  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)^M  
05-27 13:37:46.598  9348  9348 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.599  9348  9348 W System.err:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)^M  
05-27 13:37:46.599  9348  9348 W System.err: Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied^M.  
05-27 13:37:46.599  9348  9348 W System.err:    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)^M.   
05-27 13:37:46.599  9348  9348 W System.err:    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)^M.   
05-27 13:37:46.599  9348  9348 W System.err:    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)^M.    
05-27 13:37:46.599  9348  9348 W System.err:    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)^M.
```

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to execute a script on Android by setting:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command("/system/bin/sh","test.sh");

pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
File workingDirectory = new File(localPath);
pb.directory(workingDirectory);  //set the working directory for this process

Process process = pb.start();

where "localPath" is passed in after being determined via:

Context c = getApplicationContext();
final String localPath=c.getFilesDir().getPath()
```

While this is a good step, I have now discovered I cannot run any binaries I import into my working area in /data/data/com.example.myapplication.  Will start a new post for this.